# select columns matching

Tags: sql, select, union, left-join, where-clause

Newbie question. I want to do something like:

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM TABLE t1
UNION
SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t1.c1 IS NOT NULL AND t1.c2 IS NULL;
```

so if I have t1:

```
c1|c2|c3
1 | a|v1
2 | b|v2
```

and t2:

```
c1|c2|c3
1 | a|v3
2 | b|v4
2 | c|v5
3 | d|v6
```

I would get:

```
c1|c2|c3
1 | a|v1
2 | b|v2
2 | c|v5
```

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: The best I could get was a left join which would include the rows with c1 not in t1, e.g. 3|d|v6, or a left join with more strict conditions which would exclude rows with c2 not in t1, e.g. 2|c|v5

Comment: see my answer below. i tried it sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc795/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to SQL Docs, `JOIN` is faster that `SubQueries`. try this:

```
 SELECT c1, c2, c3
 FROM   t1
 UNION
 SELECT b.c1, b.c2, b.c3
 FROM   t1 a inner join t2 b ON
         (a.c1 = b.c1) and (a.c1 = b.c1)
 WHERE  (b.c1,b.c2) NOT IN (SELECT c1,c2 FROM t1)
```

to prove, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50a4e/23

Comment: your answer is correct, and yet it doesn't work on my tables and I don't know why. What happens is it repeats values with the same c1 and c2 in both tables, so the result is 
c1|c2|c3
1 | a|v1
2 | b|v2
2 | c|v5
1 | a|v3
2 | b|v4
Instead of just:
c1|c2|c3
1 | a|v1
2 | b|v2
2 | c|v5

Comment: it's because the data in your tables in not the same with your example. give us sample data the are nearly same with the existing..

Comment: I added one value to each table in your fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50a4e/1), reproducing the problem. You can see row |c1|c2)=|1|'b'| repeated with values v1.2 and v3.2. It should only be one row, |1|'b'|v1.2|, the one from t1. And the same for rows |1|'a'| from t1 and t2.

Answer (score 2):

The query should look like something like below.However,I am not sure how efficient it is.

```
SELECT 
    T1.c1,
    T1.c2,
    T1.c3
FROM T1
UNION     
SELECT 
    T2.c1,
    T2.c2,
    T2.c3
FROM T2 
WHERE ((T2.c1,T2.c2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.c1,t1.c2 FROM t1)) AND 
(T2.c1 IN (SELECT t1.c1 FROM t1))
```

Comment: Nope. In this query if a c2 value is repeated for different c1 in t2 it is only selected for the first c1. I want to union to my selection from t1 something like select all couples c1,c2 from t2 where c1 is in the selection from t1 but (c1,c2) is not, not c2 individually.

Comment: (I just corrected it so it's now a valid solution, though still not very efficient)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.c1,t2.c2,t2.c3 
from t1,t2 
where t1.c1=t2.c2;
```